# std::pair in lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I just want to know how to write pairs inside the lambda expression capture brackets.
Because the following code does not compile so I'm missing something ...

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> container1_;

for( auto iter : container1_ )
{
    auto result = std::find_if( container2_.cbegin(), container2_.cend(),
        [iter.first]( const std::string& str )->bool { return str == iter.first; } );
}

In member function ‘bool MsgChecker::CheckKeys()’:
error: expected ‘,’ before ‘.’ token
error: expected identifier before ‘.’ token
```

Comment: Try just [iter] in your lambda declaration.

Comment: lol, it works, but why is that ?

Comment: @Athanase, because you're capturing `iter`, not a method of `iter`.

Comment: Makes sense, sorry for I am a noob with lambdas !

Comment: This is a good tutorial:
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Comment: Shall we mark your answer as the right answer ? Thanks !

Comment: Why do people keep writing answers in comments?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, so that you can claim the glory! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  [iter.first]( const std::string& str )->bool { return str == iter.first; }
// ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Lambda captures are for *identifiers*, not for arbitrary expressions or anything else.

Just pass in `iter`:

```
  [iter]( const std::string& str )->bool { return str == iter.first; }
```

---

> `[C++11: 5.1.2/1]:`
>
> *[..]*
>
> *capture*:
>    *identifier*
>    `&` *identifier*
>    `this`
>
> `[C++11: 2.11/1]:` An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits. *[..]*

Comment: For posterity, expression capture via something like `[bob = iter.first]` has been proposed for C++1y (not sure of status of the proposal) in order to allow capture-by-move.  So if you are reading this in 5 years...

Comment: @Yakk Accepted into the working paper 2 meetings ago; there's text in N3690. The final syntax uses `{}` initializers, e.g., `[bob{iter.first}]`.